# Is there a speed limit for objects falling in gases or liquids?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, velocity, drag, viscosity

Let $o$ be a spherical object with mass $m$ and surface $s$.

Let $g$ be the gravitational acceleration and $h$ the height.

Let the gas where we drop $o$ in have density $d$ and pressure $p$ at height $h$.

If we drop $o$ at height $h$ what will be its speed $v(t)$ and height $H(t)$ as a function of time $t$ ?

Note that $g$ is a parameter here, not ness 9,81 as here on earth.

I know here on earth there is a speed limit to falling objects in the air.
Do we always get a speed limit?

What if we add an initial velocity to $o$ paralell to the falling direction  $v$ , where the velocity $v$ can be both positive or negative?

What is the logic and justification behind the equations and solution?
Is this analogous to sliding on a ramp with friction, or is it more like collosions with particles? Or maybe both are valid and are possible origins of the solution equations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Estimating atmospheric friction by measuring the change in velocity of a ball thrown straight upwards](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/49995/)

Comment: Also see the analysis on the [Hyperphysics web site](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mechanics/quadrag.html).

Comment: Have a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity after a long enough time its velocity reach terminal velocity. If it's drop velocity is higher than terminal velocity, it will decelerate to terminal velocity

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is terminal velocity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1989/)

Answer (score 0):

Terminal velocity of a free falling object is obtained at the moment its acceleration vanishes
\begin{equation}
\Sigma\mathbf{F}=0.
\end{equation}
The forces that act on the object while falling are the gravity force,
\begin{equation}
F_g=-mg,
\end{equation}
and the drag force 
\begin{equation}
F_d=\frac{1}{2}v_t^2dC_dA
\end{equation}
where $v_t$ is the terminal velocity, d is the density, $C_d$ is the drag coefficient and A is the cross section of the object. Substituting the expression of the forces into the force equilibrium equation we obtain
\begin{equation}
v_T=\sqrt{\frac{2mg}{d C_dA}}.
\end{equation}
This solution is written generally for any kind of falling object in inviscid fluid. For the particular case of a sphere, $A=\pi r^2$ where $r$ is the radius of the sphere. The drag coefficient value, $C_d$, can be found in the [literature](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/dragsphere.html).